# @font-face working on localhost but not in live server

Tags: css

I’m trying to install custom font in website and for that I’ve used following line of code:

```
 font-family: 'TradeGothic';
 src: url('../Content/fonts/trade_gothic_oblique-webfont.eot?');
 src: url('../Content/fonts/trade_gothic_oblique-webfont.eot') format('eot'),
      url('../Content/fonts/trade_gothic_oblique-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
      url('../Content/fonts/trade_gothic_oblique-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
      url('../Content/fonts/trade_gothic_oblique-webfont.woff') format('ttf');
 src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64, Us6SIvwGRglxYAAAAAAFQbB7XAAA) format('woff'), url('../Content/fonts/trade_gothic_oblique-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
```

It is working fine in my local host in all browsers but in the case of live server this is not working only ie7, ie8 and safari 5.0, so let me know what’s going wrong in this code.

Comment: Are the font files loaded by the browser when you're on the page hosted on the live server? Are the file paths correct? You can check that with developer tools. There might be a problem with mimetypes and .htaccess, although that's just a wild guess because there isn't enough information to diagnose your problem.

Comment: If they are not loading on any device, as in browser, tablets, phones etc, then you either did not upload the fonts to the correct directory, or you did not link the fonts properly in the CSS. If you've confirmed that all this is correct and you still have a problem, take a look at your .htaccess file and see if requests are getting intercepted.

Comment: Some links to help you out : http://paulirish.com/2010/font-face-gotchas/    http://www.fontsquirrel.com/blog/2010/11/troubleshooting-font-face-problems

Comment: Be sure to turn them off or uninstall locally to see if they are truly being served or if they are being displayed via your local file system.

Comment: Can you try hosting it on JSfiddle for us to see?